# Android: Cannot open apps on SDcard

Tags: applications, sd-card

I accidently deleted some folders on the SDCard, and now I cannot open any apps that were installed on the sdcard like angry birds.. These apps are being shown in the Settings, but I cannot move it back to phone. Only thing I can do is uninstall it. Any idea how to get these apps working? I really dont wana play angry birds from the begining all over again :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No idea about other apps but Angry Birds save data is stored to /data/data/com.rovio.angrybirds/files

If you copy over the contents to a separate location, then re-install Angry Birds and move back the old save data into the same location *after* re-installing Angry Birds, you should have the same save state.

Comment: I agree, there's no option other than to reinstall what was deleted but the saves can probably be retrieved still.

Comment: Im sure I did not delete the applications folder.. or whichever folder the applications are stored in. Like I said the apps show up in the settings. I re-installed all the applications. Now everythings working ok. And I dint lose the saved data.